# Regular expression to match Style sheet pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to write a regular expression to match the following patters

```
CSS color words such as blue,black ,etc
Hexa decimal color codes
```

How to generate a regular expression to match the above said patterns?

Edit
I would like to check only the following colors

```
aqua
black
blue
fuchsia
gray
green
lime
maroon
```

Comment: Do you need to validate color names, or somethings who looks like a color name?

Comment: Did you try anything? Which part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Rubens I need valid color names

Comment: There are 141 different color names, is regex really the tool to use here? What have you tried?

Comment: The color names are http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Comment: Are you trying to parse the css file or html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google gives the following result

[Regular expression for CSS Colors](http://www.kylirhorton.com/2008/a-regular-expression-that-matches-css-colors/)

I am not sure whether you are looking for similar patters.But at least it will give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#[0-9A-F]{3,8}|aqua|black|blue|fuchsia|gray|green|lime|maroon
```

You could also drop this regex (bad idea, IMHO) and stick with [ColorTranslator.FromHtml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

(maroon|aqua)|(#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2})

put the color names in the first section, separated by the | character